# Duplicate an alloy object

Tags: appcelerator, titanium-alloy, appcelerator-alloy

I searched and could not find an answer, so here is my doubt,

is it possible to fetch an object and duplicate it?, like, I have this code in my view (.xml):

```
<View id="endereco1" class="" layout="horizontal" height="60dp" >   
  <Label class="input-left-label label-font-size label-text-align-right">CEP: </Label>
  <TextField class="textArea"></TextField>
</View>
```

then on my Js I would like to fetch this $.endereco1, and creat and $.endereco2, changing only the id, is it possible, like instantiating the object that was written on the view?

thank you in advance

Answer (score -1, accepted):

underscore.js is built into the titanium sdk. why not simply use

```
clone 

_.clone(object) 
Create a shallow-copied clone of the provided plain object. Any nested objects or arrays will be copied by reference, not duplicated.

_.clone({name: 'moe'});
=> {name: 'moe'};
```

Comment: And how would I add it bellow my item, like <View id="endereco1" >...</View><View id="endereco2" >...</View>

Comment: @RicardoGimenesFerreira in this situation, you add the cloned object in the controller (the .js file) something like `var bar = .clone(foo);

$.parentView.add(bar);`

Comment: This is not the way to go. This is what Alloy has controllers and widgets for as suggested in http://stackoverflow.com/a/35040439/4626813

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion is that you use that object as an controller, then when you want to get the duplicate controller, send the same arguments in the creation method:

```
var copy = Alloy.createController('view',argsUsedOnFirst).getView();
```

Or create a function that returns an object like the first one:

```
var copy = function(propertiesUsedOnFirst) {

    return Ti.UI.createView(propertiesUsedOnFirst);
};
```

Comment: to add to this, I recommend this read: https://medium.com/all-titanium/using-reusable-components-in-titanium-6927acb3e3e9#.k7j81tlsm

Comment: Very nice answer, thank you very much, I am dealing with a very bad written code, with lots and lots of .tss, .xml, and .js, and documenting it is being a pain, and adding a few functionalities is being a nightmare.